# Reversing choices in Excel\Access filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

When going through a list of choices to filter in Excel or Access, I can select or deselect any specific category, and I can select or deselect all categories.

A huge time-saver option in many situation would be an option to REVERSE all selections: all selected categories are deselected, all unselected categories are selected.

I don't see such an option in the filter menus - does it possibly exist with some key shortcut? or is there another way to get the same result?

Comment: no, it doesn't exist. You may write macros for that, but also for that you won't be able to create a general one, need to adapt it for the different situations.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you can do this with VBa (I've not tested this). The code also appears to have been written and tested in Excel 2003 but I'd think it would work fine for you.

```
Sub InvertFilters() 
Dim rng_cell As Range 
    For Each rng_cell In Range("myActualFilter") 
        rng_cell.Value = Not rng_cell.Value 
    Next rng_cell 
    Range("myCheckBoxAll").Value = _ 
             Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("myActualFilter").Value) 
End Sub
```

http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2011/03/excel-multiple-value-filters-with-invert-selection.html

DigDB *appears* to offer this http://www.digdb.com/excel_add_ins/filter_invert/